# I got this error "API Request error: Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePKAZ.jpg)

im a student im still new to flutter only had few months of experience. I'm stuck at this error. Whoever is good with flutter please help.

I've had same error before but i fixed it by changing the data type. now it's something else and i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the full error as text and not as an image.

Comment: You should consider everything coming from the API as 'NULL'. Therefore, for example, the properties that I define as 'String' are called 'String?' You should convert it to e. And if the property is null after creating your model then you should act accordingly. In this code, by looking at the picture, I see that the 'name' and 'email' of the incoming response are null. The problem may be due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ur screenshot, i assume your User model has `id` and `status` are required field and your response **doesn't have `id and status`** so it is `null`. so make sure your response have field `id` and `status`